# Cutline without a geometry error

Tags: raster, polygon, clip

I have created a polygon shapefile in QGIS by creating the shapefile as a polygon, allow editing of the shapefile, then adding the polygon feature. I have set the CRS to the same CRS as the raster layer I am trying to clip. For some reason, it is giving me the "cutline feature without a geometry" error. I have experimented with other rasters and it does not seem to work. However, it would clip vector layers. Any thoughts? [image]

Comment: Have you saved your edits? It's telling you that it can't find a geometry in your polygon feature class which could mean that your edits haven't made it back to the shapefile, one or more of your geometries are invalid or the spatial references can't be made to match.

Comment: @Michael Miles-Stimson You were on to something. Saving, and restarting QGIS did the trick.

Comment: That would be because the geometry (row) isn't written to the shapefile until you save your edits, until then all your edits are held in memory. Although you can see your feature as if it's coming from the shapefile and make changes to it it's not physically there as you see it until you save edits. Most of the tools that I've seen are links to DOS commands (see the window) and will use the layer *as of the last save*.